# A tool which is able to create diagrams of a system architecture

Tags: mockups, architecture

I am searching for an easy webapp or windows application where i can design a system architecture. Creating boxes for different zones, e.g. demilitarized zone, adding servers, databases and protocols and also connecting them with each others. It should be more hardware orientied, with nice graphics of databases and computer – not like a screen mockup tool or a UML modeler. Is there something like this out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I have to recommend both [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) and [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/). I'm not sure what image sets the latest version of Visio comes with. I can state for sure that Dia offers image sets that contain the symbols that you most likely need to complete your task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) which is a general purpose SVG editor that has, by default, a plugin that allows you get images from http://www.openclipart.org/. There are quite decent pictures of Computers and Hardware that you can use.

There's also the [xfig](http://www.xfig.org/) program but it's got a very old school UI.